# how to apply search filter on foreign key in django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, youtube, sidebar

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        search_query = self.request.GET.get("student", None)
        if search_query != None:
```

return Student.objects.filter(name__contains=search_query)
return Student.objects.all()

Comment: return Student.objects.filter(name__contains=search_query)
        return Student.objects.all()

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    search_query = self.request.GET.get("student", None)
    if search_query:
        return self.queryset.filter(student=search_query)
    return self.queryset
```